# i am using angular 7 when routerLink not working when i click on anchor button it's not working

Tags: angular, angular7, angular7-router

in angular 7 i have define different component app folder and define component in route is well when i definde router name in url it,s work fine show me that component which is attached to that url but when i define that rout name in anchor tag click on anchor it,s not working here is my html code

```html
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item @@about">
  <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about">About</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item @@blog">
  <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/blog">BLOG</a>
</li>
```

this is my router

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'blog',
    component: BlogComponent
  },
];
```

Comment: Can you show us your routing structure

Comment: import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'',redirectTo:'home',pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'home',component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'about',component:AboutComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

Answer (score 9):

If your anchor tag is not becoming blue that means routerLink is not binded with anchor tag. It is because you have not imported `RouterModule`.

Note : You have to import `RouterModule` in the the module where you have declared this component where you are adding `routerLink` and not in the `app.module.ts`.
For example : if you have `home.component.ts` in `home.module.ts` and you want to use `<a [routerLink]="[/student]"></a>` in `home.component.html` then add `RouterModule` in `home.module.ts`

```
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
@NgModule(
{ 
  ...
   import:[
     ...
       RouterModule
     ...
   ]
  ...
}
)
```

Answer (score 3):

In my angular 9 case, the component with links, was declared in a Shared Module. The `RouterModule` was in the parent module. So the `routerLink` did not work.

It worked when I imported the `RouterModule` in the Shared Module also.

In case you are using `ng serve`, you may have to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Define **RouterModule** like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
])
```

Template:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item @@about">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item @@blog">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/blog">BLOG</a>
  </li>  
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Note: You must add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-hq6vkw?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: my problem is in menu list when i click on anchor it,s does not effect url

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'',redirectTo:'home',pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'home',component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'about',component:AboutComponent},
  {path:'blog',component:BlogComponent},
];

Comment: Have you added `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`?

Comment: You need to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and menu in app.component.html. You can create a menu component and add it in app.component

Comment: i have define css and js file in index.html it,s working fine but when i start clicking on anchor so then it,s not working

Comment: and i have images in assets it,s also not working when i start clicking on anchor it,s give me this error                                                                                                                       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: First concentrate on a single issue. You can share your code in stackbiltz

Comment: Just create a new stackbiltz with only routing. You donot have to add everything, And you can contact me in https://www.linkedin.com/in/adritasharma

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You need just to add this to your app-routing.module :

```
    const routerOptions: ExtraOptions = {
        scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
        anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
        scrollOffset: [0, 64],
      };
```

and in your imports :

```
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes, routerOptions)]
```

Scroll to top on Route Change in a simple way put in app.componenet.ts :

```
      onActivate() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }
```

app.component.html :

```
    <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate()"></router-outlet>
```

styles.css

```
    html {
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
```

Comment: that,s great it,s work for scroll component to top when routing thank,s

Comment: can you define that how can i scroll top in smootly during routing